# How to access full app center in live mode

Tags: release-loki, appcenter, live-installation

I managed to get elementary OS Loki to be installed in persistent USB thumb drive, which I intend to use as a portable OS.

All's great, except that I am unable to access all the apps in the App Center. I believe this is because I am in live mode.

Is there any config I can edit to enable me to have full access to the App Center?

Comment: What kinds of errors do you get? We need more context to tell whether this is a bug or particular to your install configuration

Comment: I didn't get any errors - just that no apps are showing (other than the native Elementary OS apps) regardless of which categories I selected. At this point in time, I just installed the Gnome App Center as an alternative for me to install apps.

Comment: Maybe try creating your USB using these [instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/772744/how-to-make-a-live-usb-persistent).

Comment: Does Gnome Software allow you to install applications?